# Greasemonkey script for auto-fill form and submit automatically

Tags: html, firefox, webforms, greasemonkey

As the title suggests, I want to actually brute-force (don't pay attention, useless information) using grease-monkey script by trying each word/alphabet I provide.
But as I think jQuery is more easier than Javascript itself , so I would also like to embed jQuery in it.
The second thing thats bugging me is to actually submit a form with a specific value.

And is there a way to store some values...like if "abcd" did not work in the input field then the page would refresh thus this un-intelligent script won't be able to detect that this word did not work already..and it will try that same "abcd" word again.

*Sorry for the vague details*

Comment: Your question is badly worded but let me see if I understand.
You have a list of words you want to try submitting to a form.
When the form submits then the page will refresh either to address B (meaning you got it right) or back to address A (where you started), but likely with some error message?

Comment: Well, absolutely correct and I apologize again for bad formations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lastTried = parseInt(GM_getValue("LAST", "-1"));   //GM_* will not work on Chrome to the best of my knowledge, would have to use cookies in that case. 
if((docIK.location.href == AddressA) || (docIK.location.href == AddressA?error)) //for example, pseudo code
{
  if(lastTried < wordsToTry.length){
    lastTried++;
    form.data.value = wordsToTry[lastTried];  //form.data.value is more pseudo code, wordsToTry is array of the words that you are going to provide
    GM_setValue("LAST", lastTried.toString());
    form.submit();
  }
}
else //Address B
{
   //Success
}
```

Comment: Also don't forget to deal with the case that you are prevented from continuing because you are are not supposed to be brute forcing the form.